# How to run .ps1 script using powershell 64bit exe via jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Powershell workflow is not supported in powershell 32bit mode. Thus i want to execute the script using powershell 64bit mode.How to run .ps1 script in 64bit mode via jenkins?

Comment: Don't know about Jenkins specifically, but if you can launch a whole command line, you can launch 64-bit PowerShell from a 32-bit process, such as in the following example: `c:\windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c "get-date; (Get-Item Env:ProgramFiles).Value"`

Comment: try running the following StackOverflow search >>> `[jenkins] run 64 bit powershell` <<< [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom powershell step like in this stackoverflow answer

[Executing powershell command directly in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436370/executing-powershell-command-directly-in-jenkins-pipeline)

You'll have to replace powershell.exe by the path to your powershell 64b exe

You could also use a shebang. some literature on that at [How can I use a shebang in a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216173/how-can-i-use-a-shebang-in-a-powershell-script)

Answer (score 0):

it works by calling using c:\windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe instead of c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

find more information about sysnative at https://www.thewindowsclub.com/sysnative-folder-in-windows-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that calling:

```
%SystemRoot%\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy Unrestricted -file "%~dp0\file.ps1"
```

results in the 64 bit powershell.

One can validate inside their script by printing out debug of:

```
$GE_64BitPS_Status=[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess
write-host $GE_64BitPS_Status
```