# Running powershell script inside a bash script

Tags: bash, powershell

In Powershell-
How do I run a powershell script(.ps1) inside a bash script(.sh)
I can run just the powershell script-
& .\scriptfile.ps1 
and just the bash script.
But when I try to run the powershell inside the bash script, I get 
file.ps1 : command not found
Both scripts are in the same path.

Comment: So you run .\scriptfile.ps1 and your error says file.ps1 not found??

Comment: No. It runs fine, no errors. The file not found error is when I run it inside the .sh script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying

```
.\scriptfile.ps1
```

?
That should be

```
./scriptfile.ps1
```

But also, when invoking powershell from a bash script, you'll need to either run the pwsh command like

```
pwsh ./scriptfile.ps1
```

or the first line of your Powershell script file should be a shebang (interpreter directive) like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
```

See [How can I use a shebang in a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216173/how-can-i-use-a-shebang-in-a-powershell-script)

Comment: I tried  pwsh ./scriptfile.ps1, I get- pwsh: command not found

Comment: Adding #!/usr/bin/env pwsh, give me #!/usr/bin/env : bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Comment: Also pwsh ./scriptfile.ps1, fails. pwsh not recognized as name of a cmdlet.....etc. Just .\scriptfile.ps1 by itself runs without errors. However, it fails when it's run from inside the .sh script.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using git bash on Windows 10 Pro and there it's `powershell`.
The executable is in `/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe` and it's contained in my `$PATH`.
So I can say

```
powershell ./scriptfile.ps1
# or inline:
powershell 'my script'
```

In the Ubuntu-on-Windows bash I have to say

```
powershell.exe ./scriptfile.ps1
```

Comment: For me `powershell ./scriptfile.ps1` was the only thing that worked.
`powershell scriptfile.ps1` gave an error and `powershell 'scriptfile.ps1'` gave an error.

Answer (score 1):

try to change permission and make it excutable with `chmod +x file.ps1`

Comment: I tried that before, but I get chmod is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file etc.

Comment: are you run with super user or root user?

Comment: I am running the powershell as admin.

Comment: I get the same message again when I run $ which pwsh ($ not recognized as the name of cmdlet.....). Also tried which pwsh. (which not recognized as the name of cmdlet etc)

Comment: @hithesh It sounds like you are running these commands from inside of the Powershell shell; try running them from your default shell (Bash, ZSH, etc).

Comment: @Scott Simontis This is on windows pc. So powershell is all I have. No bash etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Update the list of packages
sudo apt-get update
# Install pre-requisite packages.
sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common
# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
# Update the list of products
sudo apt-get update
# Enable the "universe" repositories
sudo add-apt-repository universe
# Install PowerShell
sudo apt-get install -y powershell
# Start PowerShell
pwsh
```