# Linter shows error SC1036 for correct powershell script

Tags: powershell, github-actions, linter, super-linter

In my [Github project](https://github.com/joergi/WireframeDownloader) I have this snippet in my [powershell script](https://github.com/joergi/WireframeDownloader/blob/main/wireframe-downloader.ps1#L14):

```
param (
    [string]$f,
    [string]$l 
)
```

The Super-linter shows me [this error](https://github.com/joergi/WireframeDownloader/runs/1217574431#step:4:62):

```
SC1036: '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?
```

but the code itself works.
I also tried a disabling of this linter rule, but this was not working, unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like the `bash` linter interprets `.ps1` as a shell file extention, you probably wanna add `FILTER_REGEX_EXCLUDE: .*\.ps1` to the `lint_bash` linter step

Comment: Why is there a `#!/bin/bash` shebang in your PowerShell script? This might be why super linter is running shellcheck instead of PSScriptAnalyzer on your script.

Comment: oh wow... I will give it a try @NathanMills, thx

Comment: @NathanMills - removing `#!/bin/bash` was the key to success.
thanks for pointing it out.
If you want, you can write it as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell scripts shouldn't have `#!/bin/bash` interpreter line (shebang). This interpreter line might confuse the linter making it run shellcheck (which is for bash/sh scripts) instead of PSScriptAnalyzer (the powershell linter).

The correct interpreter line for PowerShell on Linux/Mac is `#!/usr/bin/env pwsh`. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218913/8890345)